# Is there a function in python that helps me to take the hidden html data in a web page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to get the solution data from a crossword puzzle by using requests library in python. I can take the texts that are already given in the page but the solutions of the puzzle appears when a button on the page is clicked. I am trying to reach solution data as I reached the other data but solutions are given as empty texts. How can I reach puzzle solutions?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all('svg', attrs={'class' : 'Board-svg--34be-'})
b = a[0].find_all('g', attrs={'data-group' : 'cells'})
```

I took the data which are given as 'b' and examine it in the spyder's variable explorer and where the solution data should be was empty. However, when I inspected the html code on browser, there should be a letter.

Comment: Please provide the url. It is possible the page updates content dynamically.

Comment: Is the solution already present in the original page or will it be added dynamically later?

Comment: It is NY Times Mini Crossword Puzzle and solutions are added after clicking a button. https://www.nytimes.com/crosswords/game/mini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access dynamically generated data (via JavaScript in this case) through a simple HTTP request. This will not work with the Requests library. You're going to have to look into more sophisticated web scraping setups that also render JavaScript. This usually involves a headless browser that render the full DOM, including modifications made by JavaScript before attempting to scrape it.

Take a look at https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer for example.